# how to call UIViewController Class using Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, frameworks

I Have create a Static library /Framework using this [tutorial](http://insert.io/frameworkios8xcode6/)

For calling a view class customView **( type UIView )**we used below code

```
-(void) showMessageInViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
   if (_isEnabled) {
      NSBundle* frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
      CustomView *csView = [[frameworkBundle loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
      csView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
      [viewController.view addSubview:csView];
   }
}
```

**My Question is :**

If i create a UIViewController Class inside my Framework
then how i navigate or call it using my Class

```
-(void)showMessageInUIViewController:(UIViewController *)uiviewController
{
DetailViewController *viewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]
                                       initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController"
                                                bundle:nil];
viewController.delegate = self;
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                        initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
}
```

It shows error in .delegate and presentModalViewController

Comment: Creating a `UIViewController`  does not make sense, as this view controller will not be in the hierarchy of your app. It's either you send the current view controller as a parameter (as you do in the first part) or using delegation.

Comment: means to use framework view i always have to create UIView ? and always i have to add them as a subview?

Comment: The way in the tutorial is very weird to me. You can avoid creating the view each time by creating it only once and then use it. also you can avoid adding it as a subview by adding it once and hiding it instead of removing it each time.

Comment: Please explain a bit ? Creating view each time means ?
i have to use 5 different Views in my Framework Please guide

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: uproot you,i will try and if its working fine sure it will be accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Have a reference to the `UIViewController` that you uses your framework currently. 
in `InsertManager.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface InsertManager : NSObject

+(instancetype) sharedManager;
-(void) setViewController; // the view controller will use it to assign itself to the framework. 
-(void) startManager;
-(void) stopManager;

-(void) showMessageInViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;

-(BOOL) isManagerRunning;

@end
```

in `InsertManager.m`

```
#import "InsertManager.h"
#import "CustomView.h"

@interface InsertManager()

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isEnabled;
@property (readOnly) BOOL hasViewController;
@property (nonatomic, weak) CustomView * csView;

@end

@implementation InsertManager

+ (instancetype) sharedManager {
   static InsertManager *sharedManager = nil;
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
      sharedManager = [[[self class] alloc] init];
      // create the custom view only once. 
       NSBundle* frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
      _csView = [[frameworkBundle loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
      csView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
   });
   return sharedManager;
}
-(Bool) hasViewController {
      return _viewController != nil;
   }

- (void) setViewController:(UIViewController *) viewController {
      _viewController = viewController
     // add the views you want to it all at once, but keep them hidden.
     _csView.hidden = YES;
     [_viewController.view addSubview:csView];
    }
- (void) startManager {
   NSLog(@"Manager is running");
   _isEnabled = YES;
}

- (void) stopManager {
   NSLog(@"Manager stopped..");
   _isEnabled = NO;
}

-(BOOL) isManagerRunning {
   return _isEnabled;
}

-(void) showMessage {
   if (_isEnabled && _hasViewController) {
      // Only unhide the custom view as its already added to the _viewController and hidden.
       _csView.hidden = NO;
   }
}

@end
```

**CustomView.m**

```
  #import "CustomView.h"

    @implementation CustomView

    - (IBAction)closeButtonClicked:(id)sender {
       // [self removeFromSuperview];
       self.hidden = YES;
    }
@end
```

I hope this helps. It might needs a bit of tweaking as I just wrote it here(no compilier). Thanks.